# JS RegEx .replace() conditional patterns & subgroups

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to format belgian phone numbers. Depending on the city, the local prefix is either 1 or 2 characters long, and I can't figure how to write a single RegEx to match them all...

Here's what I've got so far, it works, but it takes 2 steps :

2 character prefix :

```
/(0{0,3}32)(93|92|89|87|86|85|84|83|82|81|80|71|69|67|65|64|63|62|61|60|59|58|57|56|55|54|53|52|51|50|28|26|25|22|19|16|15|14|13|12|11|10)([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/
```

1 character prefix :

```
/(0{0,3}32)(9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2)([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/
```

And the pattern :

```
"+$1 $2 $3 $4 $5"
```

Any idea how I can combine the two RegEx as well as using the same pattern for .replace() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regexp can be reduced to:

```
(0{0,3}32)(9[23]|8[0-79]|71|6[0-79]|5[0-9]|2[2568]|1[0-69])([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})
```

Your second one can be also reduced to:

```
(0{0,3}32)([2-9])([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})
```

This is one of the possible solutions to combine those two regexps:

```
(0{0,3}32)(?:(9[23]|8[0-79]|71|6[0-79]|5[0-9]|2[2568]|1[0-69])([0-9]{2})|([2-9])([0-9]{3}))([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})
```

Every group you need is still accessible. The indexes of the groups changed though. To retrieve the format you provided in your question, replace the matching strings by:

```
+$1 $2$4 $3$5 $6 $7
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?33p9t)

Comment: Why not just make the unneccessary groups as `non-capturing`? That will not change the matching string.

Comment: @RohitJain If I well understood the inputs/outputs, every group is used. What *unneccessary groups* are you talking about?

Comment: I mean the outer groups you created to combine those regexes. Like this: - `/(0{0,3}32)(?:(?:(9[23]|8[0-79]|71|6[0-579]|5[0-9]|2[25-68]|1[0-69])([0-9]{2}))|(?:([2-9])([0-9]{3})))([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/`

Comment: And now captured groups are same. But it really won't matter much. It still does the job. +1. And yes - `[2-3]` is same as `[23]`.

Comment: @sp00m: He's talking about `$2`

Comment: @Bergi @RohitJain I believe `$2` is neccessary to enclose the two parts of the nested `|` (see `([0-9]{2})|([2-9])`), even if it is not used to capture data.

Comment: still can be non capturing: `(?:)`

Comment: @Christoph Awesome! I have always wondered what `(?:...)` meant in regexp without really searching the answer, now I finally know. Then yeah, @RohitJain and @Bergi are both right. Thank you Christoph `;)`

Answer (score 2):

How about a custom object that encapsulates checking and formatting?

```
function BelgianPhoneNumber(inputStr) {
    var re = /0{0,3}32(?:(9[23]|8[0-79|7[1]|6[0-579]|5[0-9]|2[2568]|1[0-69])([0-9]{2})|([2-9])([0-9]{3}))([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/,
        match, area, grp1, grp2, grp3;

    if (match = re.exec(inputStr)) {
        if (match[1]) {
            area = match[1];
            grp1 = match[2];
        } else {
            area = match[3];
            grp1 = match[4];
        }
        grp3 = match[5];
        grp4 = match[6];
    } else {
        area = grp1 = grp2 = grp3 = "";
        // possibly throw error
    }

    this.toString = function () {
        if (match) {
            return ["+32", area, grp1, grp2, grp3].join(" ");
        } else {
            return "invalid phone number: " + inputStr;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var p = new BelgianPhoneNumber("003233437667");
console.log("Phone: " + p);  // -> Phone: +32 3 343 76 67

var p = new BelgianPhoneNumber("003287565656")
console.log("Phone: " + p);  // -> Phone: +32 87 56 56 56
```

I have no idea whether the two numbering schemas can overlap, though, yielding false positives when matching.

However, when in doubt the regex favors 2-digit area codes over 1-digit ones. If you want it the other way around, change the order of the "choice..." group.

An argument for a custom object is that you could easily add methods like `.getAreaCode()` or one that maps area codes to city names. And you would still be able to use it directly in a string, thanks to the overridden `.toString()` method.

The combined regex breaks down as

```
0{0,3}32               # constant prefix, therefore no group
(?:                    # choice: either...
  (9[23]|8[0-79|7[1]|6[0-579]|5[0-9]|2[2568]|1[0-69])   # 2-digit area code
  ([0-9]{2})                                            # first group (2 digits)
  |                                                     # or...
  ([2-9])                                               # 1-digit area code
  ([0-9]{3})                                            # first group (3 digits)
)                      # end choice
([0-9]{2})             # second group (2 digits)
([0-9]{2})             # third group (2 digits)
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me through understanding the regex posted earlier!